# Android - What determines which devices my phone can cast to?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm making an app that should be able to cast to TV's (Android TV & Chromecast). I have experience with Android Development, but I am still at the learning point regarding google cast.

In my environment there are few TV's (5+),and when I open Youtube app on my phone, and select Cast button, device discovers couple of TV's (2-3, or more), but when I start my app and select Cast button, my app discovers only 1 TV (same TV every time).

I want to ask if someone can explain what determines which devices I can cast to? i.e. why youtube app discovers 3+ devices to cast to, and my app discovers only 1 device. It's the same phone, same environment (same TV's), same network.

Thanks in advance for any clarification on this.

**EDIT**

Smartphone: Sony Xperia L1 (G3311).

Here is some of the TV's I'm using:

- TV #1 : Philips 43PUS6412/12 --- Android TV (V.8)
- TV #2 : Samsung 7 Series (50) - Model Code: UE50NU7402 --- Android TV
- TV #3 : Samsung 5 Series (32) - Some older model --- Android TV BOX (MI BOX, model: MDZ-16-AB)

I checked, all devices are on the same WI-FI network.

And this is even more confusing for me:

- On Youtube app I see all these TV's all the time, while
- On Sony' default "Album" app, as well as in the app I made, and google cast sample app I downloaded to phone also - at first I saw **ONLY** "MiBox", none else.
- After some time, when I tried couple of times again and again, all apps mentioned above have discovered "Philips TV", but now they didn't discover "MiBox",
- For couple of tries, apps managed to discover both "Philips TV" and "MiBox" at the same time,
- Then, again these apps discovered only "MiBox", without "Philips",
- And now again, apps see only "Philips", without "MiBox"...

I don't know what is happening, what is causing this behaviour, so please I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56142911/edit) your post with the exact test setup you have, i.e. Model names of Android TV (built in, e.g. Sony or other brand), Chromecast devices, Android TV boxes (NVidia Shield, Nexus Player) along with what is connected to what.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I added most of the test setup I use, should be enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By themselves Samsung TVs run Tizen. In the Tizen App Store there is a YouTube client which I presume the YouTube Android phone app is connecting to (you may have paired them at some point, i.e. same login credentials).

While a TV set like Philips is running Android TV, from my understanding that the running the Chromecast receiver app isn't consistent. I searched on the model and didn't see that particular model has the "Works with Google Assistant" branding or any branding that it supports "Google Cast"/"Google Chromecast".

For example Sony has a page on updating the "Built in Chromecast" app:
https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/articles/00114152

I would use that page as a guide and see if the Philips TV set has a Chromecast receiver app and is updated. My guess is that even if it does, it doesn't run the background correctly (and would have gotten the appropriate branding logos).

A similar situation exists for any Android TV box like MiBox, the Chromecast receiver app isn't consistent.

See this Reddit thread about the subject:
https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidTV/comments/74klxy/casting_to_mi_box/

If you are doing development work. I would advise at least one Google Chromecast device as a baseline since Google controls the software updates and built the hardware.

Comment: Since I didn't find any topic online regarding my questions, I guess the problem is as described above...in regards with TV, not my app. So I'll mark this answer as correct, to close the topic.